# initiate memory array in function

Tags: solidity

in all tutorials initiating a memory array inside a function is like this:

```
uint[] memory newArray = new uint[]()
```

but I can do it like this:

```
uint[] memory newArray
```

solidity version 0.8.14
is this a new update or there is a difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to allocate space in memory for `numItems` items, then you'll have to call it like this

```
uint[] memory newArray = new uint[](numItems);
```

otherwise it will basically be empty (unless you of course assign the pointer to an already existing memory array).

Comment: you can create a fixed size array like this too 
uint[numItems] memory newArray;

Comment: do you mean creating a fixed size array because i can do that inside a function like this: uint[numItems] memory newArray;

Comment: so the only purpose of first declaration is that we can assign a pointer to an storage array that is already exists?

Comment: yeah. otherwise it's just long hand for the short version